# How group ST_LengthSpheroid result by date?

Tags: postgis

I have a table with GPS coordinates and the time they were received. I need to get the path length by day. What is the correct way to do this in a PostGis database?

But when I try to make a request like this:

```
SELECT ROUND(ST_LengthSpheroid(ST_MakeLine(a.geom), 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]')::numeric, 2) AS track_len
FROM (SELECT geom, received_at FROM geolocation
      WHERE vehicle = 4 AND received_at BETWEEN '2023-03-01 12:00:00-00' AND '2023-03-10 12:00:00-00'
      ORDER BY geo_id) as a
    GROUP BY date_trunc('DAY', received_at)
;
```

then the IDE writes a warning "Column 'a.geom' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the desired result like "date : total_length" conditionally for every day?

Answer (score 0):

Let's create some example data:

```sql
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS geolocation;

CREATE TABLE geolocation(
    geom geometry(POINT, 4326),
    received_at timestamp,
    vehicle integer
);

INSERT INTO geolocation VALUES
-- 1st day, car 1
('SRID=4326;POINT(8.0 50.0)'::geometry, '2023-04-18 12:00'::timestamp, 1),
('SRID=4326;POINT(8.1 50.1)'::geometry, '2023-04-18 12:01'::timestamp, 1),
('SRID=4326;POINT(8.2 50.2)'::geometry, '2023-04-18 12:02'::timestamp, 1),
-- 1st day, car 2
('SRID=4326;POINT(7.9 50.0)'::geometry, '2023-04-18 13:00'::timestamp, 2),
('SRID=4326;POINT(7.8 50.0)'::geometry, '2023-04-18 13:01'::timestamp, 2),
('SRID=4326;POINT(7.7 50.1)'::geometry, '2023-04-18 13:02'::timestamp, 2),
-- 2nd day, car 2
('SRID=4326;POINT(7.6 49.8)'::geometry, '2023-04-19 11:00'::timestamp, 2),
('SRID=4326;POINT(7.5 49.9)'::geometry, '2023-04-19 11:01'::timestamp, 2),
-- 3rd day, car 1
-- messed up timestamps
('SRID=4326;POINT(7.3 49.6)'::geometry, '2023-04-20 10:03'::timestamp, 1),
('SRID=4326;POINT(7.4 48.7)'::geometry, '2023-04-20 10:00'::timestamp, 1),
('SRID=4326;POINT(7.2 48.6)'::geometry, '2023-04-20 10:02'::timestamp, 1),
('SRID=4326;POINT(7.1 48.7)'::geometry, '2023-04-20 10:01'::timestamp, 1);
```

I preferaby like to work with [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), as they tend to make the code more readable. As a first step, it could be necessary to sort our data. Aftwerwards, you could group (e.g. generate multipoints) all GPS points by *date* and *vehicle* using [ST_Collect](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html). Using [ST_Makeline](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) will turn them into paths. This paths can then be put into *ST_LengthSpheroid*, as shown in your example:

```sql
WITH 
-- sort by timestamp and car, just in case :-)
sorted as (
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        geolocation
    -- optional filtering
    -- WHERE 
    --  vehicle = 1
    ORDER BY 
        received_at, vehicle
),
-- Generate a multipoint per day and vehicle
multipoints as (
    SELECT 
        received_at::date as date,
        vehicle,
        ST_Collect(geom) as geom
    FROM
        sorted
    GROUP BY
        date,
        vehicle
), 
-- convert multipoints to lines
lines as (  
    SELECT 
        date,
        vehicle,
        ST_MakeLine(
            geom
        ) as geom
    FROM
        multipoints
    GROUP BY
        date,
        vehicle
)
 -- enjoy the result
SELECT 
    geom,
    date,
    vehicle,
    round(
        ST_LengthSpheroid(geom, 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]')::numeric,
        2
    ) as dist
FROM
    lines
```

Which leads to

[image: Result shown in QGIS with labeled paths]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my IDE was just highlighting these non-standard PostgreSQL functions. Simply by launching the request for execution, everything works correctly.

P.S. I am using IntelliJ Idea.